# Can't see SKU as an option on shopping cart price rules

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, sku

We're new to Magento community and I'm trying to set up a shopping cart price rule offer on a single product however I want to set it against a single SKU. When I click in the dropdown for conditions subselection, under Product attribute I only see categories and attribute set as options., This is where SKU sits as an option in Magento Go and I can't see any reason why it wouldn't on Community. Does anyone know? Is this an issue to take up with my web developer?
many thanks in advance
faye

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to edit the SKU attribute in the backend and make it available for price rules.
Go to `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes`, search for the SKU attribute, edit it and set the field `Use for Promo Rule Conditions` to `Yes`.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2.2

```
Stores > Attributes > Product

Edit 'sku' > ATTRIBUTE INFORMATION > Storefront Properties > Use for Promo Rule Conditions = Yes
```